# Is it possible to have one span a fixed width distance from another using responsive Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get one span to remain a fixed width from another span whilst still using a responsive Bootstrap grid.

I have the site up at [shifteddd.com](http://www.shifteddd.com). I'm trying to get the Info icon to sit next to the £10 text and stay a fixed distance of around 30px to the right.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you wouldn't place the info icon and £10 in the same span like this: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/CeZx5/?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid pagination-centered">
  <div class="span12">
     <h2 >£10 <span class="info-icon" title="A3 (297x420mm) 160GSM">i</span></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.info-icon{
padding-left:50px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

A variation with the price centred on the page: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/CU6X5/

Cheers!

Comment: For one, I'd like the £10 to be central. Secondly, for some reason I had real issues when trying it out and couldn't get the info icon to appear inline with the £10. Is there a way to put them both in the same span but keep the £10 central on the page? Thanks by the way!

Comment: Hey, yeah that is what I'm after, but it doesn't quite work when I add in the CSS to make it have a background and appear like a circle. Here is the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/CU6X5/6/. Any fix for my circle? Thanks again, you've been really helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I can live with that ;) If this has solved your problem, consider accepting the answer so others don't spend time on it.